# Bash JQ getting multiple values Issue in JSON file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to parse a JSON file for getting multiple values. I know how to parse the specific values ( "A"/"B"/"C") in the array `(.info.file.hashes[])`.

For Example : When issuing the following command over the file `b.json`

```
jq -r '.info.file.hashes[] | select(.name == ("A","B","C")).value' b.json
```

Result :

```
f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744
66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa
9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659
```

Where **b.json**:

```
{
  "Finish": 1475668827,
  "Start": 1475668826,
  "info": {
    "file": {
      "Score": 4,
      "file_subtype": "None",
      "file_type": "Image",
      "hashes": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "value": "f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744"
        },
        {
          "name": "B",
          "value": "66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa"
        },
        {
          "name": "C",
          "value": "9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659"
        },
        {
          "name": "D",
          "value": "4a51cc531082d216a3cf292f4c39869b462bf6aa"
        },
        {
          "name": "E",
          "value": "e445f412f92b25f3343d5f7adc3c94bdc950601521d5b91e7ce77c21a18259c9"
        }
      ],
      "size": 500
    }
  }
}
```

Now, how can i get multiple values with "Finish", "Start" along with the hash values? I have tried issuing the command.

```
 jq -r '.info.file.hashes[] | select(.name == ("A","B","C")).value','.Finish','.Start' b.json
```

and Im getting the result as:

```
f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744
null
66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa
null
9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659
null
null
null
```

Expected Result :

```
f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744
66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa
9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659
1475668827
1475668826
```

Comment: I don't know jq but it looks like you are trying to select start and finish from `.info.file.hashes[]` array.

Comment: You could also do... `jq -r '.info.file.hashes[] | select(.name).value'  b.json`

Comment: @l'L'l : Yes true , But i need only selective "values" from any of the "names" from hash. For the posted question above , Im trying to get the "Finish" & "Start" values ( 1475668827, 1475668826)   along with the selective hash values.

Comment: ^ You should add that info to your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally just downloaded and read the manual

Try

```
jq '(.info.file.hashes[] |select(.name == ("A","B","C")).value), .Finish, .Start' b.json

"f34d5f2d4577ed6d9ceec516c1f5a744"
"66031dad95dfe6ad10b35f06c4342faa"
"9df25fa4e379837e42aaf6d05d92012018d4b659"
1475668827
1475668826
```

Note the brackets used for grouping the pipe separately from the Finish and Start values.

Comment: 123: Great Thanks, Now i got it.